# UITableView with Interface Builder crashes in iOS 8 but works in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I created a `UIViewController` and added a .nib. I am not working with storyboards, but just individual .nibs for every `UIViewController` that I create.
I initialize my view controller as follows (for the shake of clarity I have not included the whole method but I have implemented `UITableViewDelegate` and DataSource methods. The problem is the following:

- In iOS 9 it works great
- In iOS 8 it stops when trying to register the Nib for table view `tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")` and says that tableView is nil. However I have connected the `IBOutlet` correctly and it works in iOS 9.

Any ideas would be extremely useful as I am puzzled!
Thanks

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: Colors.Blue.rawValue)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "MenuCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")
}
```

The `MenuViewController` is a burger menu and is loaded as follows in the AppDelegate:

```
let mainViewController = ViewController()
        mainViewController.title = "Main content"
        mainViewController.addLeftBarButtonWithImage(UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Bars, textColor: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(25, 25)))
        mainViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
        nvc.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.enabled = false

        //menu controllers
        let leftViewController = MenuViewController()
        leftViewController.title = "Menu"
        let menuController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)

        //init slide menu control
        let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: nvc, leftMenuViewController: menuController)
        slideMenuController.removeRightGestures()
        slideMenuController.closeLeft()

        self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

UPDATE:

Solved this by following the comments to load the nib programmatically inside the view controller's init() that I created.

Comment: Is it tableview that is nil or nib?  How do you load *this* view controller?

Comment: the tableview is nil, not the nib.  I've updated my question to include how the view controller is loaded.

Comment: You aren't loading `MenuViewController` from a nib, so it won't have any outlets set. I can't see how this would work on iOS 9 either

Comment: Wait. How to I load it from a nib? Following tutorials they all say to add the uitable view in nib and then reference it to the view controller with an outlet. And I initialize menu viewcontroller from code, isn't that enough?

Comment: If you just initialise the MenuViewController as you do then no nib is loaded so there are no objects associated with the IBOutlets. You need to use `loadNibNamed` although really I would suggest adopting storyboards

Comment: Thank you! Will try that. Unfortunately this is the beginning of a large project of a team of 6 people from different locations and using storyboards seems to be restricting since not all view controllers have been designed yet so we do not know their number. Probably storyboards would however be something to rethink. Thanks again!